# Java non-responsive thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am writing a TicTacToe game program, I have all the methods created and am in the debugging stage however I am getting a non-responsive thread issue. This thread created in my Runnable handler class does not respond:

```
     public void run(){

    Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
    if(gui.playTwoFirst.isSelected()&&gui.computerPlay.isSelected()){
        myTurn = true;
       }
    while (playing == thisThread){
       if(myTurn == true){

          takeTurn();
       }else{
          //wait for my turn

       }
    }
}
```

Once the runnable method is called the thread never recognizes the, "myTurn" boolean may become true, and the takeTurn(); method is never called, so the game in effect halts.
If I use this code it works:

```
     public void run(){

    Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
    if(gui.playTwoFirst.isSelected()&&gui.computerPlay.isSelected()){
        myTurn = true;
       }
    while (playing == thisThread){
        System.out.println("");
       if(myTurn == true){

          takeTurn();
       }else{
          //wait for my turn

       }
    }
}
```

The only difference is a small System.out.println(); which does nothing, but for some reason permits the thread to see that myTurn has become true, and permits the takeTurn() method to be called.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You need to learn about synchronization between threads. Doing a busy loop constantly checking for a boolean value is almost never a good idea, and will use 100% of your CPY doing nothing. And it will only work if the boolean is volatile. Threading is a very hard topic. Buy and read "Java concurrency in practice". That said, I don't see why you would need a thread in a simple GUI program like this, which should be event based.

Comment: Thank you JB, I figured it was something along the lines of pegging a monitor or resource to 100%. The reason for the threading is the GUI is all full of bells and whistles and listeners, I wanted some practice with game interactions. MSSQL uses resource pools through the Resource Governor, does Java have a parallel model to balance threads' allocation of resources? I will take a look at the book reference you made